# How to programmatically retrieve version number of a library?

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to update a cell in a spreadsheet when a new version is saved but I can't find a way to retrieve the version number ...

**UPDATE**: I create an [issue](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1369)

Comment: If you want your script to be able to get the project version that it is running within then please go "star" @Edo 's corresponding [feature request (#1369)](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1369).  Your star equals a vote for this feature.  (The request is in the official Apps-Script issue tracker, [according](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/support#missing-features) to the official Google Apps Script Support page.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently, there's not a way to retrieve this information. Please raise this in the [issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list), and be sure to include details about your specific use case. For example, do you want to be able to retrieve information about all versions or only the most recent version?

Comment: Thank you Jan, I create an issue http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1369

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to write a little Apps Script you may use one of the properties functions, either the Script Properties or the User Properties.  These are described here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/service_properties

I use the script properties to attach version numbers to files created when I run scripts, so not exactly the problem you're asking about, but related.

Comment: By the way, here's a code scrap that does the "right" thing to increment the version number each time I run:var documentVersion = parseInt( ScriptProperties.getProperty("documentVersion") ) + 1;
  ScriptProperties.setProperty("documentVersion", documentVersion);